# Meaning Full name

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'textBlock', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
    toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic' ],
    styles: [
      { name: 'Title', element: 'h3' },
      { name: 'Meta', element: 'h5' }
    ]
  }) }}
```

Is it possible to change the Add Rich text to some different name

Answer (score 1):

Inside your root directory update the `app.js` file with the following:

```
var apos = require('apostrophe')({
    ...

    // The modules you want to use.
    modules: {
        ...
        'apostrophe-rich-text-widgets':{
          label: 'Awesome Text'
        },
        ...
   }

})
```

For example if you want to have "Add Awesome Text" button then, just updating the `label` property of the configuration options of the `apostrophe-rich-text-widgets` module with the value of "Awesome Text" will give the desired result. Note that the value of the `label` should not start like "Add ..", instead apostrophe will prefix the given value with the word "Add".

Answer (score 0):

This thing works but only problem with this is every text changes , i want to specify each text

for eg: ADD heading , Add Paragraph , ……